# Recursive Widget in Flutter - type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart, recursion, types

I'm trying to do some basic stuff, such as use a recursive function to generate a tree view in the main page of my app.

Here the process summarized:

1. retrieve the entire tree structure from firestore as single document. The structure of document is like this (pseudo-doc):

```json
{
   tree: {
       total:"3",
       name:"A name",
       children[
           {
               total:"4",
               name:"Another name",
               children:[
                   {},...
               ]
           },
           {
               total:"5",
               name:"Main name",
               children:[
                   {},...
               ]
           },
       ]

   }
}
```

2. use a Widget to parse the structure of document retrieved and then display the tree.
   Since I'd like to manage some states inside each level (e.g. open/close, ecc), I'd choose a Stateful Widget (`Levels`). Here's the code snippet (without state management):

```dart
class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
    const MainPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
            //get doc from firestore!
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('taxonomy_tree').doc("main_tree").snapshots(),
            builder:(context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>snapshot){
                if(!snapshot.hasData) return Text("Loading");
                else {
                    
                    Map<String, dynamic>? tree = snapshot.data?.data();
                    if(tree != null){
                        return Levels(elements:tree["tree"] as Map<String,dynamic>,level:0.0);//call Levels Widget
                    } else return Text("No data");
            
                }
            }
        );
    }
}

class Levels extends StatefulWidget {
    Levels({Key? key, required this.elements, required this.level}) : super(key: key);

    final Map<String, dynamic> elements;
    final double level;


    @override
    _LevelsState createState() => _LevelsState();
}

class _LevelsState extends State<Levels> {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
        List<Map<String, dynamic>> el = widget.elements.containsKey("children") ? widget.elements["children"] as List<Map<String, dynamic>> :[];
    
        return Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:widget.level*10),
            child: ListView(
                children: [
                    Text(widget.elements["name"] ?? ""),
                    Text(widget.elements["total"]?.toString() ?? "0.0"),
                    //OUCH! el[i] seems to cause an ERROR
                    for (int i = 0; i< el.length;i++) Levels(elements:el[i], level: widget.level+1) 
                ]
            )
        );
    }
}
```

When the code tries to call `Levels` with argument `el[i]` I get the following erorr:

`type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>' in type cast`

I've tried to cast `el[i]` explicitly (`el[i] as Map<String,dynamic>`) but still get the error.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: try building streambuilder in statefulwidget

Comment: Hummm...It seems pointless to me but thanks for the comment. I tried anyway, why not, and it doesn't work

Comment: I asked you to use streambuilder for the betterment of your code and it's not an answer since I commented it!

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because when you are creating another object of your class `Level` your condition

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> el = widget.elements.containsKey("children") ? widget.elements["children"] as List<Map<String, dynamic>> :[];
```

runs again inside the object class

but your next `children`

```
     children:[
                   {},...
               ]
```

doesn't have any data which means it will return

> Map<dynamic, dynamic>

to get rid of this problem just fill some data in your another `children` of the data tree like below

```
{
  "tree": {
    "total": "3",
    "name": "A name",
    "children": [
      {
        "total": "4",
        "name": "Another name",
        "children": [
          {"data": 121}
        ]
      },
      {
        "total": "5",
        "name": "Main name",
        "children": [
          {"data1": 4545}
        ]
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Diwyansh but this is not the case. I've posted a pseudo json, the real json are filled correctly. I think the deserialization is the solution here. Thanks anyway

Comment: I have run this code successfully and it's working fine after making above changes as you are creating Object inside object then you also have to make sure that your containskey condition is true or not, can also attach a screenshot of needed.